# iptables directing traffic through vpn

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables

Networking newbie. I have two interfaces on the host: `eth0` and `tun0` from my OpenVPN client.  The IP addresses are:

```
eth0    192.168.1.22
tun0    10.1.0.8
```

### Question 1

For **outgoing** traffic by changing the destination address to that of `tun0` will it force it to use the vpn?

**No, but using gateway address for tun0 does.**  Tested with the following:

```
    iptables -t nat -N VPN
    iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -j VPN
    iptables -t nat -A VPN -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.170
```

Where `10.1.0.170` was the gateway address for VPN (found using `ip route`).

1. The above example creates a NEW (`-N`) chain for the nat table (`-t`).
2. The jump to the VPN chain is from `OUT` (straight after local app). Using insert (`-I`) to supersede other rules in OUT.
3. It's implied that for traffic originating from any source change destination to gateway of `tun0` device.

### Question 2(a)

For outbound traffic is the destination address the IP address of the interface `eth0` or is it the gateway address?
Assuming `eth0` is default interface/gateway.

### Question 2(b)

For traffic generated from local app what is the source address?

### Question 3

Can this be solved purely by iptables or do I need to modify the routing table? As both interfaces are on the same host (i.e. same debian box).

**Additional Info**

I'm trying to understand the principles so I can apply it to my case. There are three I address subnets in total, the third is in the range 172.17.42.1/16 associated with another virtual interface `docker0`.

Essentially I want to direct traffic from *just* 172.17.42.8 via the VPN.

Comment: Why are you trying to solve this with `iptables`? A proper routing table is the way to go.

Comment: Because I'm ignorant! :) I've seen solutions were people have enabled ip forwarding and others where they've setup two different routing tables with respective default gateways. I don't know the 'right' way to do this but based on examples seen apparently should do it but seems too easy.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Send all traffic to `192.168.1.22` (or `192.168.1.0/24`) through your VPN? Or all your internet traffic?

Comment: I want all traffic from a specific ip address to go though vpn. I've seen lots of examples forwarding *from* vpn but not many *to* vpn using iptables.

Comment: Routing doesn’t work on source addresses, but destination addresses. If you want a specific client to use a VPN connection, this very client should establish its own VPN connection.

Comment: Not sure I understand your last comment. I can an `ip rule` that says if source address = x. X. X. X then use table vpn. Set the default gateway to use tun0.

Comment: That’s policy routing and an advanced topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost the excellent figure linked from the ArchLinux wiki iptables page is useful in identifying packet flow through the various `iptables` chains (at the bottom of the answer).

### Backup

```
iptables-save > back.up.file
```

Check for your flavor of Linux distribution, I needed to add `sudo` as I wasn't root.

### Question 2(a), 2(b)

To determine source and destinaton addresses I found the `LOG` and `TRACE` functions very useful:

```
iptables -t filter -I OUTPUT -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 10 -j LOG  --log-prefix "ABC-LOG-PREFIX "
```

The default table is `filter` but I've stated it explicitly so you can see syntax, especially if you want to explore other tables `mangle`, `nat` etc.  I've inserted the rule `-I` because I wanted packets to be logged before other rules were applied.  Added a rate limit so log file doesn't become saturated `-m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 10`.  Finally added a prefix so log file can be searched easily `--log-prefix`.  For example, on Linux Mint:

```
cat /var/log/kern.log | grep "ABC-LOG-PREFIX"
```

Secondly for debugging, the `TRACE` command will track a packet through the entire process:

```
IPTABLES -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j TRACE
```

Warning, this will trace **all** tcp packets, for more info see [Admin Berlin](http://adminberlin.de/iptables-debugging/)

### Question 3

As both interfaces (`eth0` and `tun0`) were on same host, from the packet filter diagram below you can see for outbound traffic they start at the same point.  Which route a packet takes is determined by the default gateway and its associated interface, which can be determined using `iproute2` by running:

```
ip route
```

This will show default gateway, which interfaces are used for what address ranges.

### Packet Flow Diagram

[image: iptables packet flow diagram]

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're talking about split-tunneling (or rather, trying to disable it).

Take a look at the redirect-gateway directive in OpenVPN: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect

Comment: You are correct this isn't what I want. I've add more context to question.

Comment: See additional info.

Answer (score 0):

In the following examples the vpn device name is tun0 (OpenVPN) and the VPN gateway is 172.21.23.172

#1 - Install VPN on your Linux router (I'm using ipvanish w. openvpn)

#2 - Route traffic using iptables

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o [VPN dev] -j MASQUERADE
```

example:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

#3 - Configure routing tables (to ensure that all traffic is routed through the VPN)

```
sudo ip route add default via [VPN ipv4 address] dev [VPN dev]
```

example:

```
sudo ip route add default via 172.21.23.172 dev tun0
```

#4 - Check that devices on the network are indeed routing thru the VPN by running these commands:

Windows:`tracert 1.1.1.1` Linux:`traceroute 1.1.1.1`

you're done!